# Functions and Relations Predicate logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If we are given a set universal set $U$ and another set $X$, how do we know if the given set $X$ is a relation on $U$ or a function on $U$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $X\subset U\times U$, then we say $X$ is a **relation** on $U$.